# Image of function in group with composition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions

I have a set S and a group $G \subset Map(S, S)$. I define a function $p$ s.t. $p \circ p = p$ and suppose its range is $T \subset S$, I must show that the range of any other function $f \in G$ is also $T$. Finally I consider the restriction of $p$ on $S\setminus T$, name it $q$, and I have to prove that the restriction of $f$ on $S \setminus T$ can be defined as $f|_{S \setminus T} = f|_T \circ q$ and is bijective.

The only thing I have managed to do is recognise that $p$ is the identity of the group, but I don't know how I could use it.

Comment: If $p$ is the identity of $G$, then for any $f \in G$, $f = p \circ f$, so $\operatorname{range}(f) = \operatorname{range}(p \circ f) \subseteq \operatorname{range}(p)$. And with $p = f \circ f^{-1}$, $\operatorname{range}(p) = \operatorname{range}(f \circ f^{-1}) \subseteq \operatorname{range}(f)$.

Comment: Thank you that is clear now, what about the second part of the question?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the motivation for this question. If the group operation is function composition, then all the maps in $G$ should be invertible. This means $T=S$, so $S-T= \emptyset$.